# Enemy chasing player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am trying to write a script for an enemy to chase a player for about 2 seconds and then stopping. I want to have the player run into a boxcollider and when this happens the enemy will chase the player for 2 seconds. I've been trying for a while and had no luck. I'm hoping someone with more skill can help me write this code so it works properly using Unity 2d. Thanks

```
void Start()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().playerBox;
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    //If the player is touching the knights targetting box, then run the command to chase.
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        isChasing = true;
        chase();
    }
}
public void chase()
{
    if (isChasing)
    {
        var x = playerTransform.position.x - enemyTransform.position.x;
        var y = playerTransform.position.y - enemyTransform.position.y;
        knightRB.velocity = new Vector2(x / 20, y / 20);
StartCoroutine(StopChasing());
    }
}
IEnumerator StopChasing()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    isChasing = false;
}
```

Comment: What specifically is your question? You aren't ever invoking your StopChasing method anywhere so thats never going to be executed.

Comment: Your chase only occurs once. So the whole is chasing seems redundant

Comment: @jhambright my question is how would I get the enemy to chase the player. Using the equations and variables I have. If the player collides with a the trigger for the enemy to begin chasing, then have the enemy chase after the player for 2 seconds. I forgot to include the stop chasing but I would include it under the knightRB.velocity line so that after 2 seconds the enemy will stop chasing the player.

Comment: @BugFinder sorry, was going to include it under knightRB.velocity line :)

Comment: You should update your original question with the information you've added here in the comments to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You new code still makes no odds. Only thing changing is the velocity but it only changes as you hit the trigger. The coroutine almost pointless. Because you can leave and retrigger the chase as much as you like and nothing changes after 2 seconds that matters

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implementation:

```
Transfrom target;
bool isChasing;
float speed = 5;
RigidBody knightRB;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sets up the knight
void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    knightRB = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Checks for a collision with the player
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    //If the player is touching the knights targetting box, then run the command to chase.
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Player" && !isChasing)
    {
        StartCoRoutine(ChaseSequence());
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// handles the chase
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Chase();
}

void Chase()
{
    if (!isChasing)
        return;

    var direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
    knightRB.MovePosition(transfrom.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * speed); 
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Stops and starts the chase sequence
IEnumerator ChaseSequence()
{
    isChasing = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    isChasing = false;
}
```

There are some assumptions I have made. Mainly that the this script belongs on the knight. Also the collider is what interacts with the environment. Meaning physically. If you have a trigger that does the detection you should be using `OnTriggerEnter` instead of `OnCollisionEnter`

Comment: This works, however the chase function does not. Not sure if it's because of the variables, but when I put the code into my script everything works (tested with debug) except for the actual chasing, the transform.position doesn't work and I'm not sure how to fix it. Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Maybe do kinghtRb.position?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Okay so transform is spelt wrong in the equation and that was the problem lol, but the enemy still does not move. Everything else is working except for the moving equation.

Comment: 1. Check that `speed is > 0`

Comment: 2. This is the movement function I tend to use. works for online games as well: ` transfrom.transform = Vector3.Lerp(transfrom.position, transfrom.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * speed);`

Comment: any way you could update that into your code? You keep using 'transfrom', and that the top is says Transfrom target; which doesn't make sense. Do I have to make a variable like 'public Transform transfrom;' because it is still giving me errors.